# Using snapd instead of flatpak in Linux Mint

Tags: bash, npm, intellij-idea, webstorm, flatpak

I installed IntelliJ and WebStorm on my Linux Mint distro. The problem I have is that I cannot use the integrated terminal on both of the software. In both of them there is a problem with my bash binary location. I researched and saw that the software manager in Linux Mint installs flatpak software by default, and that it works as a sort of a container. I tried to change the location of my bash binary to `var/run/host..` but it didn't seem to work.

I read that people solve this by installing the tar version of the software or using snapd. Since snapd is not supported by Linux Mint, what are my alternatives? Can I somehow give access to my software to use my bash, npm, etc... and if not, why is it that flatpak makes these things so difficult?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatpak works as a sandbox environment - each pack has its own runtime environment and because of security reasons, flatpak apps do not have direct access to host files. There could be a lot of problems due to this.

Please try reinstalling the IDE using one of the officially recommended options (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installation-guide.html) - download the `tar.gz` from https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/#section=linux, or use the [toolbox app](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installation-guide.html#toolbox) to manage installations

Comment: I used the toolbox from jetbrains and its amazing. Thank you so much!!